# Force Calculation script of Cell Range in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

For some reason the formula isn't working when the data from importrange is being updated. What I have to do is to go to cells and pressing F2+enter to refresh and ya it works like that I tried creating a macro and it also works but I want it to be simplified.

I come up with this kind of script that doesn't really work because i don't have time to learn for and dig deeper for scripting

```
function CellRefesher() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:O52");
  range = SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

so What I'm trying to do is I want to do something like force calculation for the cell range of A1 to O52 and base of google document(just base on my understanding) 
this "`SpreadsheetApp.flush();`" will do something similar that's why I do this `"range = SpreadsheetApp.flush();"`

This might be like a spoon feeding but please do help me. I want to learn but don't just have much time yet. Thank you

Comment: Are there threads useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18835689 https://stackoverflow.com/q/25163243

Comment: As pointed out by the answer in Tanaike's comment, `flush()` is not what you need. If you provide more information on how you import range and which calculation you want to perform (add spreadsheets, code, formulas, snippets etc.) it will easier to understand your problem.

Comment: What I am importing is a timestamp from googleform responses, on the sheet where I imported the data I'm separating the Timestamp date and time,

Comment: Sample timestamp, 1/1/1111 12:12:12. to separate those two what I do is =int(timestampcell) for date and =trime(right(timestampcell,9) then concatinating them with the email respondent. and on another sheet is a date and email where I vlookup on by the concatenated columns which sometimes i need to open the cell code (pressing f2) then enter to make the lookup value appear. sometimes when value work appear and I highlighted the cell the value already on the highlight but not visible on cell itself very wierd

Comment: So which cell exactly is the one that does not update automatically and how is this cell populated (with a script, a formula, on trigger...)? I am asking because if the cell is populated e.g. on time trigger, you need to wait for the values to update, while if an onEdit() trigger is used - the values will only updated after a manual (not programatical!) edit takes place in the sheet. Hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your sheets, formulas and code.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: i forgot to add that I am using arrayformula on those INT() and trim(right()) which works perfectly. the only thing is the data won't be visible until I press f2+enter which looks like a recalculating the cell

Comment: You mean each time a new timestamp, 1/1/1111 12:12:12 is imported you want to apply a formula to the new cell? And the timestamp is inserted automatically by the a Google Form on each form submit?